# Android: Tracking devices with issues

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, audio-recording

Is there an updated list, service or otherwise that keeps track of "problem devices" for Android?

For example, some devices do not support Android's default audio encoder, AMR_NB. Some devices need a full projection with arguments to access Android's content providers. Some devices do not support the "content://sms" Uri. With all these random issues flying around, is there a way to track these problem devices which require specific fixes?

I just can't believe we're supposed to throw our apps into the public domain then deal with issues from problem devices as they arrive. There has to be a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the answer is no.

You can't predict the specific fixes for problem device before they occur.

While you can only have post deployed analysis from app through bug tracker such as **ACRA**

Also to make sure certain feature for device specification you can go though specific model white papers.

These documented white papers specific to phone models are easily available to us for certain big brands only such as :
**SONY , Motorola , Samsung**

Comment: The white papers route seems to be a long, tedious option for a weekend project. Do they cover deviations from android standards in the white papers?

Comment: yes it's time consuming you would only be able to concentrate on few of them in limited time . These papers refers to the hardware the software(driver) details that the company has modified in that model say to get Hdmi support etc.

Comment: thank you for the more relevant answer. Hopefully some day one of us can compile an ongoing list we can all access.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, some devices do not support Android's default audio encoder, AMR_NB.

AMR_NB is not a default audio encoder. The [documentation for `MediaRecorder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setAudioEncoder%28int%29) states "If [setAudioEncoder()] is not called, the output file will not contain an audio track", so AMR_NB is not the default encoder for `MediaRecorder`. `AudioRecord` uses PCM. If you have evidence to suggest that AMR_NB is a default somewhere, please supply a link.

That being said, the media APIs for determining what encoders are supported on a device have historically been lacking.

> Some devices need a full projection with arguments to access Android's content providers

Unless otherwise documented, you need to supply a non-`null` projection with any query of a content provider. Projections do not have arguments.

> Some devices do not support the "content://sms" Uri.

That content provider is not part of the Android SDK, and therefore anyone trying to use it should *expect* that it will not exist, or will not contain the desired data (e.g., third-party SMS clients might store their messages in their own database).

With all that in mind, to return to your original question:

> Is there an updated list, service or otherwise that keeps track of "problem devices" for Android?

Not really. Some development houses no doubt maintain their own internal lists (e.g., Rovio is probably well aware of graphics limitations on various devices).

Comment: Thanks for the very verbose answer. I suppose the only solution is building my own list using ACRA as the issues come in.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the answer is "no".